# Nextjs13 and react leaflet: Dynamic loaded Marker in FeatureGroup unable to call getBounds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, leaflet

I currently play around with the new nextjs13 and the app directory as well as server side only code. In my project i use React leaflet and this cannot be directly used anymore in Nextjs13 (with the app directory). It is required to load the client components differently or via `dynamic`. In my project i use the 2nd option via `dynamic` and created a File for the components that can be lazy loaded:

```
const ClientSideMap = dynamic(() => import('@components/Map'), { ssr: false })

type Props = {
    center?: number[];
    locationValue?: string;
    children?: ReactNode;
};
  
const ClientMap = forwardRef((props : Props, mapRef) => (
    <ClientSideMap {...props} forwardedRef={mapRef} />
))
ClientMap.displayName = 'ClientMap';

export default ClientMap;

const ClientSideMarker = dynamic(() => import('@components/Marker'), { ssr: false })

type MarkerProps = {
    center?: number[];
    locationValue: L.LatLngExpression;
    children?: ReactNode;
    id: string | number;
};
  

export const Marker = forwardRef(({ center, locationValue, children, id }: MarkerProps, markerRef) => {
    return (
        <ClientSideMarker locationValue={locationValue} id={id} ref={markerRef}>
            <Popup>
                {children}
            </Popup>
        </ClientSideMarker>
    )
})
Marker.displayName = 'Marker'
```

These dynamic components are loaded in the `app/page.tsx`file

```
import Map, { Marker } from '@components/MapLazyComponents'

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic";

export default async function Home() {
    const result = await getData() || {};

    // console.log("Data", result)

    return (
        <main>
            <div style={{
                width: '400px',
                height: '400px'
            }}>
                <Map>
                    {result.map(m => (
                        <Marker key={m.id} locationValue={[m.lat as number, m.lng as number]} id={m.id}>{m.id} - {m.name}</Marker>
                    ))}
                </Map>
            </div>
        </main>
    );
}
```

When I run this project, it works like expected and i can see a map with the configured markers.

I would like to set the Zoom the map in that way, that all Markers are visible. Leaflet offer a possibility for that use-case by using `getBounds`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Map test", featureGroupRef.current, featureGroupRef.current?.getLayers())
    if (map && featureGroupRef.current) {
      console.log("Bounds", featureGroupRef.current)
      // map.fitBounds(featureGroupRef.current.getBounds());
    }
  }, [map, featureGroupRef]);
```

Unfortunately, this is not working (Error: `Error: Bounds are not valid.` - [Thrown in that Line](https://github.com/a-marcel/nextjs13-app-dynamic-loaded-marker/blob/main/components/Map.tsx#L24)). After some debugging i assume that this is reladed to the dynamic loading of Markers. In the code lines above, you can see that i log some lines after the Map is loaded. The Layers the Map is empty but in the console.log it's possible to see that there is an array with layers that contains the Marker.

Since this is a more complex problem, I created a github repo where the issue is visible. https://github.com/a-marcel/nextjs13-app-dynamic-loaded-marker/tree/main

Thanks a lot

P.s.: I know that I can change the way and pass the marker data via Json down to the MapComponent without a use of dynamic. But I really would like to use it in the way where everything is prepared in the `page.tsx`file - so on the server side.